# Fake JNDI when not in App Server

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I have an application that can be ran under Tomcat and standalone. Currently, I use JNDI to configure my DB end points. JNDI only works when an application is run under an application server however (Tomcat in my case), so when the application is run standalone the JNDI call fails, and the application throws an Exception.

Is there a way that you can 'mock' a JNDI datasource so that the application can run without an app server? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Is the stand alone mode only for testing?  Or is it also a valid operational mode?

If it is for test only I would write your own context factory which implements a minimal InitialContextFactory and just specify that class in your config file.  You class responds to requests with the appropriate resource.

If it is also a valid operational mode you could put more work into your context factory and use it as a proxy for the app server.  It determines if the app server is present and if it is the request is redirected to the app server.

If you google 'Mocking JNDI' there are a couple of good examples of how to do this.